# Grab data from a post request with Python 3

Tags: python, post, request

Can anyone help me to grab the date from this website?
I want to get the data from the new website after I click "Submit Query". That needs a post request because a form being submitted

https://henke.lbl.gov/optical_constants/pert_form.html

I tried multiple methods (post request) online but all failed. Don't know why.

Many thanks!

Comment: get request is used to grab data. also it will return you the html page. I suggest using beautifulsoup or any other web scrapper to do the job.

Comment: @Goion I want to get the data from the new website after I click "Submit Query". That needs a post request because a form being submitted

Answer (score 0):

If You want to grab text contents of page for example, try:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://henke.lbl.gov/optical_constants/pert_form.html')
print(r.text)
```

For more go to https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: I want to get the data from the new website after I click "Submit Query". That needs a post request because a form being submitted.